# Autofocus problem on new Nikon D5300

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, shutter, shutter-lag, nikon-d5300

I have a new Nikon D5300.  It takes approximately 3 seconds between pressing the shutter release button halfway and getting autofocus.  I get an autofocus to beep almost immediately and the green focus dot comes up in the viewfinder, but I don't have focus at this point, I have to wait another 2-3 seconds.  Manual focus is ok.  Has anyone else experienced anything like this...?

I have tried three different lenses with the same result and have tried changing camera settings.  The problem happens in all kinds of lighting, on a tripod, and with remote shutter release.  I am running out of things to try.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this is a fault with the camera (as you have tried different lenses). As your D5300 is new, I would take it back to the shop I bought it from and they should repair or replace it.